# Npm multiple file script (lessc)

Tags: css, node.js, powershell, less

I'm trying to run a `lessc` PowerShell commandline in my `package.json`.
So in my scripts section I have something like that:

```
Get-ChildItem *.less -Recurse | ForEach-Object {lessc $_.FullName > $_.BaseName.css}
```

but it's giving me the following error:

> 'Get-ChildItem' is not recognized as an internal or external command

while this is executing normally in PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem *.less -Recurse | ForEach-Object {echo $_.Name}
```

A plain `lessc` command also works as expected.

Any ideas?

[Also check this question that have another solution for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691173/how-do-i-compile-a-directory-full-of-less-css-files-to-css)

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests that you're not running the statement in PowerShell. `lessc` is a node.js application, not a PowerShell command, so it's unsurprising that it works when used by itself.

To be able to use PowerShell cmdlets you need to run the statement in PowerShell, e.g. like this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem  *.less -recurse | Foreach-Object{ lessc $_.FullName > $_.BaseName.css }"
```

Comment: A powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command is also needed before the Foreach command.Thanks

Comment: @ArgiropoulosStavros No. You run the entire statement in a single `powershell.exe` process. If you need a second one you most likely have an issue with quotes or unescaped characters. For further troubleshooting you need to show the actual content of your `package.json`, not just the command you're trying to run.