# LESS pre processor integration in React JS

Tags: reactjs, less

I was trying to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master) to start with react. I wanted to add LESS pre-processor in my app. In the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc), it is only mentioned about SASS to use **node-sass-chokidar**.

What to use for LESS?

Comment: If _less_ is installed globally, you should be able to use _lessc_ for the the _build-css_ and _watch-css_ tasks in your _package.json_

Comment: Or do a _yarn add less_. The problem is, though, it's more complicated to set up the _build-css_ and _watch-css_ jobs, because the command line API of Less is not very user friendly. See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691173/how-do-i-compile-a-directory-full-of-less-css-files-to-css